# Slideshow of Images

Tags: iphone, image, ios, ipad, slideshow

I am developing an application of simple slideshow.

Description : In the application I've 5 images stored in an array.Currently I'm displaying the images into a scroll view but I want to show a slideshow of the images stored in the array. how can I do that ? Any tutorials ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using an NSTimer, here's some basic code. However the "page" number has to be calculated somewhere, according how you'd like to handle the edge cases, for example: last image in slide show.

Have a look at [Apple's example app PageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html), which shows a nice way how to handle memory efficiently in a paging scrollview.

```
self.slideTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                                   target:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(slide) 
                                                 userInfo:nil 
                                                  repeats:YES];

...

- (void)slide
{
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * nextImagePageNumber;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

**[NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)**

> You use the NSTimer class to create
>   timer objects or, more simply, timers.
>   A timer waits until a certain time
>   interval has elapsed and then fires,
>   sending a specified message to a
>   target object. For example, you could
>   create an NSTimer object that sends a
>   message to a window, telling it to
>   update itself after a certain time
>   interval.

Comment: Thanks Nick Weaver. Can you please tell me what is this "slideTimer" ? Can you provide me some descriptive idea on this slideshow scenario ? It'd be a lot of help. Thanks

Comment: The slideTimer ist just an instance of an [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html), see the the assignment and creation: it fires every 3.0 seconds and sends the message `slide` to self.

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can have NSTimer for sliding images automatically across the scrollview. i.e. you need to programatically scroll the scrollview according to your requirement on the NSTimer basis. You can set the time interval between the sliding of 2 Photos.

Hope this leads you in the correct pathway. If you have further query please leave a comment I will definitely help you for the same.

Comment: Thanks Jennis. Can you please provide some more description on this ?

Answer (score 0):

http://lievendekeyser.net/index.php?module=messagebox&action=message&msg%5Fid=1351

Comment: Thanks for the response but I've mentioned that this thing I've done. Now I want to show the images without swiping the screen(Using some timer etc).